# Replace values in a dataframe with values from another dataframe - Regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have input data like as shown below. Here 'gender' and 'ethderived' are two columns. I would like to replace their values like 1,2,3 etc with categorical values. Ex - 1 with Male, 2 with Female

The mapping file looks like as shown below - sample 2 columns

[image]

Input data looks like as shown below

[image]

I expect my output dataframe to look like this

[image]

I have tried to do this using the below code. Though the code works fine, I don't see any replace happening. Can you please help me with this?

```
mapp = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
for col in mapp:
    if col in data.columns:
        print(col)
        s = list(mapp.loc[(mapp[col].str.contains('^\d')==True)].index)
        print("s is",s)
        for i in s:
           print("i is",i)
            try:
               value = mapp[col][i].split('. ')
               print("value 0 is",value[0])
               print("value 1 is",value[1])
               if value[0] in data[col].values:
               data.replace({col:{value[0]:value[1]}})
            except:
                print("column not present")
   else:
       print("No")
```

Please note that I have shown only two columns but in real time there might more than 600 columns. Any elegant approach/suggestions to make it simple is helpful. As I have two separate csv files, any suggestions on merge/join etc will also be helpful but please note that my mapping file contains values as "1. Male", "2. Female". hence I used regex

Also note that, several other column values can also have mapping values that start with 1. ex: 1. Single, 2. Married, 3. Divorced etc

Looking forward to your help

Comment: You could loop through your columns and first create a dict, then apply a  `.map` to replace the key with the value pair. Not at laptop so I can't show an example but that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with nested dictionaries - first key define colum name for replace and another values for replace created by function [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['1.Male','2.Female', np.nan],
                   'Ethnicity':['1.Chinese','2.Indian','3.Malay']})
print (df)
     Gender  Ethnicity
0    1.Male  1.Chinese
1  2.Female   2.Indian
2       NaN    3.Malay

d={x:df[x].str.extract(r'(\d+)\.(.+)').dropna().set_index(0)[1].to_dict() for x in df.columns}
print (d)
{'Gender': {'1': 'Male', '2': 'Female'}, 
 'Ethnicity': {'1': 'Chinese', '2': 'Indian', '3': 'Malay'}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':[2,1,2,1],
                   'Ethnicity':[1,2,3,1]})
print (df1)
   Gender  Ethnicity
0       2          1
1       1          2
2       2          3
3       1          1

#convert to strings before replace
df2 = df1.astype(str).replace(d)
print (df2)
   Gender Ethnicity
0  Female   Chinese
1    Male    Indian
2  Female     Malay
3    Male   Chinese
```

Comment: ohhh a nested dict. That's neat. Dind't know it could also be used

Comment: @jezrael - There are few columns which aren't replaced. I verified the regex and it seems to work. Can you think of any reason other than regex why it may not replace?

Comment: @SELVA - Hard question, it seems some data related problem. So the best is check if columns names matching (exactly same names) - e.g. by `print (sorted(d.keys()))` with `print (sorted(df1.columns))`, if all matching then identify which columns are not replaced and check `print (d['col not repalaced1'])`, `print (d['col not repalaced2'])` with `print (df1['col not repalaced1'].astype(str).unique())` , `print (df1['col not repalaced2'].astype(str).unique())`

Comment: When I print one of the columns of dataframe, the value displays as 1.0 in jupyter whereas in Excel/csv it is 1, can this be any issue?

Comment: I mean my dataframe also has columns which aren't present in mapping file. but that shouldn't be a problem right, as we are matching and replacing based on names?

Comment: @SELVA - yes, because replaced strings numbers, solution should be in pandas 0.240 by `df1.astype('Int64').astype(str).replace(d)`

Comment: @SELVA - No, it is not problem if another columns, only is necessary test if not some typo in columns which should be same

Comment: Okay, am seeing those keys being generated in dictionary (d) successfully but the replace alone isn't happening

Comment: Anyother way to convert to int64? df1.astype('Int64').astype(str).replace(d) this statement throws error

Comment: @SELVA - Ok, so matching `print (d['col not repalced1']) with print (df1['col not replaced1'].astype(str).unique())` for all problematic values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194158/discussion-between-jezrael-and-selva).

Answer (score 1):

If the entries are always in order(`1.XXX,2.XXX...`), use:

```
m=df1.apply(lambda x: x.str[2:])
n=df2.sub(1).replace(m)
print(n)
```

---

```
   gender ethderived
0  Female    Chinese
1    Male     Indian
2    Male      Malay
3  Female    Chinese
4    Male    Chinese
5  Female     Indian
```