# Select rows based on columns which doesn't have a specific value and make use of dictionary - Python & Excel - Big Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have more than million records and 700 columns stored in a csv like format. Each record represents each person and all the values in each of the columns represent his responses to survey questions.

So, I have given a piece of code of sample input data with two cols

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person_id':[1,2,3,4,5],
'Gender':[np.nan,np.nan,'1.Male','2.Female', np.nan],
               'Ethnicity':['1.Chinese','2.Indian','3.Malay',np.nan,np.nan]})
```

Input data frame based on the above code looks like as shown below

[image]

From the above dataset, we can see that person_id = 1, has value only for Ethnicity column. Similarly, person_id = 3, has values for both gender and ethnicity columns

Here comes the use of dictionary and it looks like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0':['Gender','Ethnicity','Location','Age_at_test','Date of Birth'],
 '1':['gen','eth','loc','age','dob']})
```

[image]

So, I would like to create an output in new excel sheet as shown below in the screenshot

[image]

Observation_id - Just a primary key like thing. Unique for all records

You can see from the screenshot, there is no person_id = 5, because both of his values were NA. Hence I would like to retain records which are not NA. For example, Person_id = 3 has two records because he has values for both the columns.

So, for example, I might have 700 rows for person_id = 45 if he has data for all the 700 columns.

Similarly if person_id = 47 has all NA's/empty for 700 columns, I will have no entry for him in the output sheet.

In essence, I would like to transform the data as shown in screenshot. The unique thing here is instead of usual dropna, I would like to retain the records(rows) but only drop the columns(features) of the person.

Can you help me as to how can I achieve this end-end data transformation done?

Any solutions to address this problem would be helpful. I can manage it to scale it up from there or break my data into chunks and do part by part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop the rows for which ALL the columns contain NaNs do this:

```
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
```